# Ubuntu 12.10 internal error: evolution-calendar-factory

Tags: 12.10

My Ubuntu keep prompting this: Sorry, Ubuntu has experienced an internal error.

and the messages are:

```
ExecutablePath
  /usr/lib/evolution/evolution-calendar-factory
Package
  evolution-data-server 3.6.0-0ubuntu2
ProblemType
  Crash
Title
  evolution-calendar-factory crashed with SIGFPE in g_cclosure_marshal_VOID_OBJECTv()
```

I am running Ubuntu 12.10 on my i3-3220 3.8GB memory

Any suggestions? please. I don't know why that happens..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First remove evolution:

```
sudo apt-get remove evolution
```

If that won't remove it, then go to the ubuntu software center, and remove it. After it is removed, if you want to reinstall evolution. Then by using bash:

```
sudo apt-get install evolution
```

Or reinstall by using the software center.